# Change power plan when laptop gets plugged in

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

On my laptop I have the 3 standard Windows 7 power plans. I want my laptop to automatically change the power plan, when I plug in the power to my laptop.

I couldn't find this feature, am I missing something?

(I want to have the powersaver plan when my laptop isn't plugged in, and the high performance when it's plugged in)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each power plan has settings for "on battery" and "plugged in" it will switch between the two automatically you don't need to create separate plans. See below if you need clarification:

[image]

If you insist on running multiple power plans that switch dynamically based on triggers [Power Plan Assistant](http://powerplan.forbootcamp.org/features.htm) should do what you want. If neither of these is what you are looking for then you may need to clarify your question.